# How to combine multiple sed and awk commands?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, sed

I have a folder with about 2 million files in it.  I need to run the following commands:

```
sed -i 's/<title>/<item><title>/g;s/rel="nofollow"//g;s/<\/a> &bull;/]]><\/wp:meta_value><\/wp:postmeta><content:encoded><![CDATA[/g;s/By <a href="http:\/\/www.website.com\/authors.*itemprop="author">/<wp:postmeta><wp:meta_key><![CDATA[custom_author]]><\/wp:meta_key><wp:meta_value><![CDATA[/g' /home/testing/*

sed -i '$a]]></content:encoded><wp:status><![CDATA[draft]]></wp:status><wp:post_type><![CDATA[post]]></wp:post_type><dc:creator><![CDATA[Database]]></dc:creator></item>\' /home/testing/*

awk -i inplace 1 ORS=' ' /home/testing/*
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run the first command, it cycles through all 2 million files, then I move on to the second command and so on.  The problem is that I'm basically having to open files 6 million times in total.

I'd prefer that when each file is opened, all 3 commands are run on it and then it moves on to the next.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered [Perl](https://www.perl.org/)? **Precisely *this*** is why Perl exists (IMO).

Comment: How long will one file take? Perhaps you should divide your folders in subfolders/batches first. More cpu's one one system and want parallel processing? Perhaps on different disks.

Comment: I think you first will make a backup. `sed -i` will make a temp file as well. I would redirect the output to new files.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no **Precisely _this_** is why AWK exists. Perl exists for when you have to do more than just manipulate text. Edward - edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output, don't expect us to try to reverse-engineer what you need a script to do by reading a bunch of other scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton I disagree; I have a few little sed scripts and a little awk script and I want to combine and run them on a massive number of files is exactly when I use Perl. And yes, I know AWK could do it too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand you can do that with perl, but it's not `Precisely why` perl exists - awk could already do all of that long before perl was invented and perl wasn't invented to be just another tool that can do what awk could already do. It is, however `Precisely why` awk exists - manipulating text like this is **ALL** that awk exists to do.

Comment: If you have 2 million files, you should consider looking at using GNU Parallel, especially with `-m` option. Try searching here on SO to get some ideas.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Agreed. I wrote in csh,sed,awk for 10 years [in any combination]. Then, I discovered perl. I quickly realized that it could replace _all_ that and I rewrote everything to just use perl. One advantage of perl is being able to precheck the scripts using `perl -c`, sort of like a compiler, before actually running them. Now, 20 years later, I've got 250,000 lines of perl and have never looked back. perl [and python] are compiled full blown programming languages that can also do what a shell does or a pattern manipulation program like sed/awk does--and much, much more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your files are small enough for a single file to fit into memory as a whole (and assuming *GNU* `sed`, which your use of `-i` without an option-argument implies):

```
sed -i -e ':a;$!{N;ba}; s/.../.../g; ...; $a...' -e 's/\n/ /g' /home/testing/*
```

<sup>`s/.../.../g; ...;` and `$a...` in the command above represent your actual substitution and append commands.</sup>

`:a;$!{N;ba};` reads each input file as a whole, and then performs the desired substitutions, appending, and replacement of all newlines with a single space each.<sup>[1]</sup>

This allows you to make do with a single `sed` command per input file.

---

<sup>[1] Your `awk 1 ORS=' '` command actually creates output with a trailing *space* instead of a newline. By contrast, `'s/\n/ /g'` applied to the whole input file will only place a space *between* lines, and terminate the overall file with a newline (assuming the input file ended in one).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything in one awk command as something like:

```
awk -i inplace -v ORS=' ' '{
    gsub(/<title>/,"<item><title>")
    gsub(/rel="nofollow"/,"")
    gsub(/<\/a> &bull;/,"]]><\/wp:meta_value><\/wp:postmeta><content:encoded><![CDATA[")
    gsub(/By <a href="http:\/\/www.website.com\/authors.*itemprop="author">/,"<wp:postmeta><wp:meta_key><![CDATA[custom_author]]><\/wp:meta_key><wp:meta_value><![CDATA[")
    print $0 "]]></content:encoded><wp:status><![CDATA[draft]]></wp:status><wp:post_type><![CDATA[post]]></wp:post_type><dc:creator><![CDATA[Database]]></dc:creator></item>"
}' /home/testing/*
```

but that doesn't mean it's necessarily the best way to do what you want.

The above relies on my correctly interpreting what your commands are doing and is obviously untested since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output. It also still relies on GNU awk for `-i inplace` like your original script did.